# python: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python

I cannot seem to understand why my code is displaying this error.

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Code:

```
l = ['Simpson', ',', 'Bartholomew', 'Homer', 'G400', 'Year', '2']
x = '{}'* len(l)
print(x)
x.format(l)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were looking for an unpacking:

```
>>> x.format(*l)
'Simpson,BartholomewHomerG400Year2'
```

Comment: Related: [*What does the Star operator mean?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/416224)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in just *one* argument, the list `l`, while your format string expects there to be 7 arguments.

If you wanted each element *in* `l` to be formatted, then use the `*arg` call syntax:

```
x.format(*l)
```

You want to print the return value, though:

```
result = x.format(*l)
print(result)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print(x.format(*l))
Simpson,BartholomewHomerG400Year2
```